# Can I use the timeline of an embedded video as data slicer

Tags: microsoft-excel, video

I would like to explore data captured during motorsport events.

Ideally I would have an embedded video in Excel and as I move the timeline of the video I can highlight/filter the values of several data series. e.g.

at 1:04.20 in the video timeline
- Lateral Acceleration was 0.5g
- Vehicle speed was 75kph
- GPS latitude was xxx
- GPS longitude was yyy

Is this possible? There are packaged software but they don't give the freedom of Excel

Comment: I suppose you can setup some kind of excel dashboard so that when you move the slider the various items refresh. Further, you could build a VBA script to update the dashboard based on the time data, that would may make it look like you were watching a video...

Comment: Just [Check this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/slicers-api-power-bi-embedded/),, possibly it  help you !